# Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array while creating new AzureMediaServicesClient

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-media-services

I am currently trying to setup a demo project to work with `Azure Media Services v3` but am running into an issue when trying to instantiate a new `AzureMediaServicesClient`.

I'm following the example that is provided [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/configure-connect-dotnet-howto).

When I do a test run, it gets to the `CreateMediaServicesClientAsync` method and then errors out when trying to create a new client. Below is the exact line that is failing:

```
return new AzureMediaServicesClient(config.ArmEndpoint, credentials)
{
    SubscriptionId = config.SubscriptionId
};
```

When I debug and put a breakpoint, I can see that `config.ArmEndpoint` is a `URI` that seems to be populated correctly. Credentials also seems to look as expected so I'm not sure what is causing the following error when trying to debug.

Error:

> Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array

Stack Trace:

> at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.Add(T item)
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.AzureMediaServicesClient.Initialize()
>
> at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Media.AzureMediaServicesClient..ctor(Uri baseUri, ServiceClientCredentials credentials, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm stumped at what the issue could be.

Answer (score 1):

Answered on the MSDN forum - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3c712b1b-e1f2-4388-a02b-4b8769cf97eb/cant-instantiate-a-new-azuremediaservicesclient?forum=MediaServices

Hi,

Which one of the tutorials are you currently following?  Have you been able to successfully run any of the sample tutorials up in docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-files-tutorial-with-api

Also, are you connecting with an AAD Service Principal?  I recommend highly that you walk through the tutorial and use the details in the article on Accessing the API here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/access-api-cli-how-to

Using the CLI is the easy way to create a Service Principal and get back all the correct settings for the application configuration. Let me know if that works for you. 
Thanks,

John